# App crash on using Fabric - Cannonball in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I've got this error when ran CannonBall:  [app here](https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-ios)

**'[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.'**

Appdelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {        
    let welcome = "Welcome to Cannonball! Please onboard with the Fabric Mac app. Check the instructions in the README file."
    //assert(NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("Fabric") != nil, welcome)

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics(), Twitter(), Digits(), MoPub()])//error here


    if Twitter.sharedInstance().session() == nil && Digits.sharedInstance().session() == nil {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let signInViewController: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInViewController")
        window?.rootViewController = signInViewController as? UIViewController
    }

    return true
}
```

I get a suggest is "missing Fabric APIKey from your info.plist".
But i can't find Fabric key in my info.plist.

Info.plist:

[image]

Comment: yes there must be a Fabric value with api key in info.plist

Comment: Ok. How to get consumerKey and consumerSecret of Digits?

Comment: did you register with fabric??/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your .plist file:

```
<key>Fabric</key>
<dict>
    <key>APIKey</key>
    <string>Your-key</string>
    <key>Kits</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Crashlytics</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict>
                <key>consumerKey</key>
                <string>Your-consumerKey</string>
                <key>consumerSecret</key>
                <string>Your-consumerSecret</string>
            </dict>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Twitter</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict>
                <key>consumerKey</key>
                <string>Your-consumerKey</string>
                <key>consumerSecret</key>
                <string>Your-consumerSecret</string>
            </dict>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Digits</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```